# Simple script brings back nonesense error

Tags: android, linux, shell, android-emulator

I have been trying to make a shell script for android that removes certain files to harden the device slightly against attack. This script has worked on an android emulator on ubuntu running froyo i think. when i try to run it on a windows box running 4.2 it brings up the error at the bottom. I have checked all the directories and they exist. I am running this using the adb.

```
echo             ANDROID
echo      HARDENING STARTED
#removing files in the /system/xbin directory
mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/mdblock0 /system
    rm  /system/xbin/tcpdump
            rm  /system/xbin/su
#removing files in the /system/bin directory
                    rm  /system/bin/bootanimation
                    rm  /system/bin/dumpstate
                    rm  /system/bin/ping
                    rm  /system/bin/ping6
mount -o ro,remount /dev/block/mdblock0 /system
echo                    ANDROID
echo              HARDENING COMPLETE
```

Brings back this error.. I have no idea whats going on.

```
ANDROID
HARDENING STARTED
mount:No such file or directory
, No such file or directorytcpdump
, No such file or directorysu
, No such file or directoryootanimation
, No such file or directoryumpstate
, No such file or directorying
, No such file or directorying6
mount:No such file or directory
ANDROID
HARDENING COMPLETE
```

PLEASE HELP

Ryan

Comment: you may have an issue with dos vs unix line ending chars. When installing under windows, use `unix2dos filename` and installing to android use `dos2unix filename`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The directory `/system` does not exists, so your `mount` command fails.

Next you try to delete a couple of files from the non-existing and thus not mounted `/system` directory, which result in more errors.

Finally, you try to remount the `/system`, which still does not exists, resulting in your last error.

Only thing is that the errors messages are a bit garbled, the filenames are overwritten by the message somehow.

**Edit**: To answer your additional question...

If you can [check if the file exists](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test) you can handle this situation properly (instead of using wildcards):

```
# Check which device to use
if [ -e /dev/block/mdblock0 ]; then
  device=/dev/block/mdblock0
elif [ -e /dev/block/mtdblock0 ]; then
  device=/dev/block/mtdblock0
else
  echo "Device not found";
  exit 1;
fi

mount -o rw,remount $device /system
# etc...
```

I do not know the exact Android shell commands, but assuming it is quite similar to bash this should work.

Comment: /system definitely exists which is why it confuses me.

Comment: What about `/dev/block/mdblock0`? If it does not exists, the mount fails, resulting in all the other errors as well

Comment: you my friend are a legend... on the older emulator its mdblock0 on this its mtdblock0   thank you very much.   is there anyway i can wildcard the mount point so this is portable to different versions?

Comment: @user1979810, the garbled error messages indicate you have carriage returns in the file, so use a text editor that allows you to save in unix file format, or use `dos2unix`

Answer (score 1):

Change the line ending to Unix style, will solve all your problem.